# How do I call my printArray function in both my flipHorizontal and flipVertical functions in order to flip my code each time it is run?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, 2d

I am currently taking a computer science course called Intro to Computer Science where I am learning Python (Python 3) and I doing an assignment having to do with flipping 2D arrays. I have written some code for my assignment already and I already have it running sequentially as it tells me to in the instructions but I am having some problems flipping it each time. What I want to know is: How do I call my printArray function in both my flipHorizontal and flipVertical functions in order to flip my code each time it is run?  I have the assignment instructions and an instructor's comment on my assignment.

**Here are the instructions:**

[image]

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
def printArray(N):
    for r in N:
        for c in r:
            print(c,end = " ")
        print()
    print()

def flipHorizontal(N):
    Array = []
    for i in range(0,len(N)):
        pos = []
        for j in range(0,len(N[0])):
            pos.append(N[i][len(N[0])-j-1])
        Array.append(pos)
    return Array

def flipVertical(N):
    newArray = []
    for i in range(0,len(N)):
        newArray.append(N[len(N)-i-1])
    return newArray

Array1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0,0], [0, 2, 0, 0,0], [0, 2, 2, 0,0], [0, 2, 0, 2,0],[0, 2, 0, 0,2]]
printArray(Array1)
flipedHor = flipHorizontal(Array1)
printArray(flipedHor)
flipedVer=flipVertical(Array1)
printArray(flipedVer)
```

**Here is the comment:**

[image]

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Just add `printArray(Array)` before `return` in `flipHorizontal` and `printArray(newArray)` before `return` in `flipVertical` …

Comment: Just replace `return newArray` with `print(newArray)`, which I think is what the comment means.

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading correct , you just need to add print statement in your defined functions.

```
def printArray(N):
    for r in N:
        for c in r:
            print(c,end = " ")
        print()
    print()

def flipHorizontal(N):
    Array = []
    for i in range(0,len(N)):
        pos = []
        for j in range(0,len(N[0])):
            pos.append(N[i][len(N[0])-j-1])
        Array.append(pos)
    printArray(Array)
    return Array

def flipVertical(N):
    newArray = []
    for i in range(0,len(N)):
        newArray.append(N[len(N)-i-1])
    printArray(newArray)
    return newArray

Array1 = [[0, 2, 0, 0,0], [0, 2, 0, 0,0], [0, 2, 2, 0,0], [0, 2, 0, 2,0],[0, 2, 0, 0,2]]
printArray(Array1)
flipedHor = flipHorizontal(Array1)
flipedVer=flipVertical(Array1)
```

Comment: ...and remove the `return` statements as per instructions

Comment: It is not mentioned that you shouldn't be saving the array. All it says print function should be inside the function.